# Unable to instantiate a stack with a list

Tags: f#

I am struggling to decipher what this error means:

> A unique overload for method 'Stack`1' could not be determined based
>   on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may
>   be needed. Candidates: System.Collections.Generic.Stack(capacity: int)
>   : unit, System.Collections.Generic.Stack(collection:
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable) : unit

This error occurs when attempting to write this code:

```
let prepareDeck deck: Card list =
    let stack = System.Collections.Generic.Stack<Card>(deck)
    stack
```

**I thought a list was of type IEnumerable.
Thus, I thought I could just drop the list inside of a Stack constructor.**

What am I missing?

Here's the rest of the code:

```
type Suit = | Spades
            | Clubs
            | Diamonds
            | Hearts

type Face = | Two | Three | Four | Five 
            | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
            | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = {Face:Face; Suit:Suit}

let private suits = [Spades; Clubs; Diamonds ; Hearts]
let private faces = [Two; Three; Four; Five; Six; Seven; Eight; Nine; Ten;
             Jack; Queen; King; Ace]

let deck = [for suit in suits do
            for face in faces do
                yield {Face=face; Suit=suit}]


let prepareDeck deck: Card list =
    let stack = System.Collections.Generic.Stack<Card>(deck)
    stack
```

Comment: Since you seem to be learning F#, see if you can avoid using `Stack<T>`, which is a mutable type. The default F# `list` already gives you stack-like features, because you can cons a new head onto a list, and you can read the head of the list.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the guidance although my skull hurts as I try to shift to this methodology of thinking.

Answer (score 3):

The way your code looks now, `Card list` is the result of the function rather than type annotation on an argument. That's why it probably looks for a stack constructor that returns a `Card list` rather than a `Stack`.

Try this:

```
let prepareDeck (deck: Card list) =
    let stack = System.Collections.Generic.Stack<Card>(deck)
    stack
```

Comment: Freaken parenthesis! Thank you.

Comment: @ScottNimrod From your recent questions here, I get the impression that the use of parentheses are giving you trouble. Perhaps the best way to view parentheses in F# is to realise that they're *optional*. The F# syntax doesn't dictate the use of parentheses. What instead happens is that often you need to **group** expressions together to override the default evaluation priority. It's just like maths: `1 + 2 * 3 = 7`, but `(1 + 2) * 3 = 9`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Unfortunately, I was never good in math. But I do have a better understanding now (from getting burned repeatedly). For now on, I just need to program such that I isolate expressions and arguments from associated constructs. Or when frustrated with the compiler, I'll immediately throw some parenthesis at the problem. Sad, I know...